# Перевод сказанных слов в микрофон в текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, распознавание-речи

хотел спросить доступна ли от гугла или другого ресурса такая возможность для своего сайта, которая предусматривает перевод сказанных слов в микрофон в текст. В основном перевод 1-2 слова.

Comment: ![http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/lu88J5JL8Hw/mqdefault.jpg](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/lu88J5JL8Hw/mqdefault.jpg)

Comment: чем в итоге воспользовались?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы, от гугла - да, для Chrome: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input

Второй вариант: http://wami.csail.mit.edu/